# Python regex with "or" condition

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract some parts from one file. The original text is like this:

```
part1
i like it
part2
no, i do not need it
part3
yes, 10 minutes;
```

**however, some files contain part3, some donot;** Now my task is to extract from part1 to part3 (if exists) using python. This is what I got:

```
> for index in range(1, 4):
>         reg_str = r"part"+str(index)+"(?P<part"+str(index)+">[\s\S]*)"+r"(?:part"+str(index+1)+"$|$)"
>         m = re.search(reg_str, total)
```

but, I always got a mixture, for example, the outcome for part1 turns out to be every part from the file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) the string at `part`?

```
>>> re.split("part[123]", str)
['', '\ni like it\n', '\nno, i do not need it\n', '\nyes, 10 minutes;']

>>> [ part for part in re.split("part[123]", str) if part ]
['\ni like it\n', '\nno, i do not need it\n', '\nyes, 10 minutes;']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [findall](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
In [27]: pattern = re.compile('part[1-3]\n(.*)')
In [28]: pattern.findall(s)
Out[28]: ['i like it', 'no, i do not need it', 'yes, 10 minutes;']
```